# error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’

Tags: c++, comparison, operators

I am trying to understand why my c++ compiler is confused with the following piece of code:

```
struct Enum
{
  enum Type
  {
    T1,
    T2
  };
  Enum( Type t ):t_(t){}
  operator Type () const { return t_; }
private:
  Type t_;
    // prevent automatic conversion for any other built-in types such as bool, int, etc 
  template<typename T> operator T () const;
};

  enum Type2
  {
    T1,
    T2
  };

int main()
{
  bool b;
  Type2 e1 = T1;
  Type2 e2 = T2;
  b = e1 == e2;

  Enum t1 = Enum::T1;
  Enum t2 = Enum::T2;
  b = t1 == t2;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation leads to:

```
$ c++ enum.cxx
enum.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
enum.cxx:30:10: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Enum’ and ‘Enum’)
   b = t1 == t2;
          ^
enum.cxx:30:10: note: candidates are:
enum.cxx:30:10: note: operator==(Enum::Type, Enum::Type) <built-in>
enum.cxx:30:10: note: operator==(int, int) <built-in>
```

I understand that I can solve the symptoms by providing an explicit `operator==`:

```
  bool operator==(Enum const &rhs) { return t_ == rhs.t_; }
```

But really what I am looking for is the interpretation of why comparing `enum` leads to an ambiguity only when it's done within a `class`. I wrote this small enum wrapper since I am required to only use C++03 in my code.

Comment: You have an `operator T ()` making the `Enum` convertible to **any** type. That invites lots of ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call is ambiguous as both the `Enum::Type` and `int` versions are valid with a single implicit conversion, the former using the `operator Type` conversion and the latter using the `operator T` template conversion operator.

It is unclear why you have a conversion to any type, but if you remove that operator, the code [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9645e0b6c8281cec).

If you are using C++11 you should use [scoped enums](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea023105b538eb0c) instead.

Comment: I tried hard *not* to have a converstion to any type...see my comment

Comment: If you want a type safe enum in C++03, you are best off providing all the operators yourself rather than implicitly converting to the underlying enum.

Answer (score 0):

`enum` can be implicitly converted to `int` (as far as I understand it is caused by backward compatibility to `C`. If you can use `C++11` you can use `enum class` to solve this issue because scoped enums do not allow implicit conversion to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` is implementation defined integral type which is mostly `int`. Now whatever operator you implement for `enum` is like you are implementing operator for type `int`. And redefining the any operator for integral types such as `int`, `double`, `char` ... is not allowed as it will change basic meaning of the programming language itself.